# Make highchart legends as a individual buttons

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to make legends as buttons. It should be separate button.

I have tried following styles but it gives whole section as a button

```
 legend: {
                enabled: true,
                backgroundColor: '#29a2c6',
                borderRadius:3,
                symbolWidth:30
            },
```

[image]

But i need like

[image]

Comment: In highchart, a legend was a single object for its style and other stuff, when you change some property of legend object that effects on entire object.
check API: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend/legend

Comment: yes. it is affecting whole svg. Is there any options to achieve this?

Comment: Use [legend.itemStyle](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.itemStyle) to style a separate item in the legend

Answer (score 0):

The Highcharts API lets you customize the item's legend styles in two ways:

Using [`itemStyle`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.itemStyle) with some CSS restrictions:

> Only a subset of CSS is supported, notably those options related to text. Defaults to { "color": "#333333", "cursor": "pointer", "fontSize": "12px", "fontWeight": "bold" }.

or

Using both [`useHTML`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.useHTML) and [`labelFormat`](http://labelFormat)

```
legend: {
    useHTML: true,
    labelFormat: '<span class="span-legend-item">{name}</span>'
},
```

and setting your styles in a separeted CSS Class

```
.span-legend-item {
    background-color: #666;
    color: #fff;
}
```

[jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/mcerrotta/tzLz7u2a/)

This maybe is not exactly what you are looking for. But It could be a good starting point.